# Как повернуть Label?

Tags: c#, winforms

Возможно в C# повернуть существующий label на 30°?

Comment: Хостить `WPF`- элемент

Comment: Либо рисовать через OGL или DX либо воспользоватся wpf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проще всего выводить повернутый текст следующим образом.

Делаем это в событии `Paint` или методе `OnPaint`.

```
public class RotatedLabel : Label
{
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        //e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(20, 20);
        e.Graphics.RotateTransform(30);            
        e.Graphics.DrawString(Text, Font, Brushes.Black, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

В `RotateTransform` задаём угол.

В `TranslateTransform` задаём отступ от края контрола, чтобы повёрнутый текст весь уместился. Эти значения зависят от размера шрифта. Конечно, желательно их рассчитывать в зависимости от него.

Размер самого лейбла нужно увеличить, чтобы повёрнутый текст влез. `AutoSize` лучше отключить.